# Python Script skipping for loop

Tags: python, json, loops, debugging

I am trying to iterate through some json data, but the information is found on several pages.  I don't have a problem working through the first page, however it will just skip over the next set.  The weird thing is, it will execute fine while in debug mode.  I'm guessing its a timing issue while working with the json loads, but I tried putting sleep timers around that code and the issue persisted.

```
url = apipath + query + apikey
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

for x in data["results"]:
    nameList.append(x["name"])
    latList.append(x["geometry"]["location"]["lat"])
    lonList.append(x["geometry"]["location"]["lng"])

pagetoken = "pagetoken=" + data["next_page_token"]
url = apipath + pagetoken + apikey
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
for x in data["results"]:
    nameList.append(x["name"])
    latList.append(x["geometry"]["location"]["lat"])
    lonList.append(x["geometry"]["location"]["lng"])
```

Comment: I think you copy pasted your code twice if I'm not mistaken, and I think your post is supposed to end at `pagetoken = "pagetoken=" + data["next_page_token"]`

Comment: No this is correct.  This is how you go to the next page.  You need the next page token found on the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it did end up being a timing issue.  I placed a 2 second timer before the second request and it now will load the data just fine.  I guess Python just couldn't keep up.

Comment: well then I think you are supposed to accept your own answer so the thread closes

Comment: Thank you!  This is my first post, I wasn't sure how to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that `data["results"]` equates to a `None` value and therefore calling `for x in None:` would result in the program skipping your for loop. Have you tried putting a print above the for loop? Perhaps try `print(data["results"])` before going into your loop to ensure the data you want exists. If that returns `None` then maybe try just `print(data)` and see what the program is reading.

Comment: That was my first guess, unfortunately that is not the case.  If I run it in debug mode, the script runs fine.  It's almost as if when I run it normally, the json takes too long to load.